# Regex validation matching pattern1 and pattern2 in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a string against two patterns both patterns must match the string. You could imagine it as some sort of validation chain.

Patterns in below code are just examples.

```
<?php
$pattern1 = "^hello hi$";
$pattern2 = "^h?llo hi$";

// form pattern that checks that both patterns match
$pattern3 = "/".??."/";

if(preg_match($pattern3,$string))
{
  //solved it
}
?>
```

I know code below is a possible solution, but I'm interested to know can it be done with one preg_match by joining patterns together somehow.

```
<?php
$pattern1 = "/^hello hi$/";
$pattern2 = "/^h?llo hi$/";


if(preg_match($pattern1,$string) && preg_match($pattern2,$string))
{
  //solved it
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead to make sure the string matches all the patterns you want, before retrieving the value. Something like:

```
/^(?=PATH_1$)(?=PATH_N$).*/
```

So for your example it would be

```
/^(?=hello hi$)(?=h.llo hi$).*/
```

[`DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/bS7fU1/1)

Comment: Ended up using `/(?=^hello hi$)(?=^h.llo hi$).*/`

Comment: @user1740331 It's exactly the same (in this case at least)

Answer (score 0):

not sure is this what you want but:

```
$pattern1 = "/^hello hi$/";
$pattern2 = "/^h?llo hi$/";
$pattern3 = "/^h[e?]llo hi$/";

if(preg_match($pattern3,$string))
{
  echo 'Y';
}else{
  echo 'N';
}
```